# How to add the code file for a second ViewController

Tags: swift2, xcode7

pardon me for beginner's question.
Besides the first default ViewController with its companion file `ViewController.swift`, I created a 2nd viewcontroller and know how to move to it. 
How do I add a companion `SecondViewController.swift` for it?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Storyboard or Xib ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Xib then

1) Goto file->New->iOS->Source->Cocoa Touch Class

[image]

2) Select UIViewController as your Base Class and name your class and also check the checkbox with "also create Xib File" click next and click finish.

[image]

Now you have a new ViewController with a file associated with it.

And if you are using storyboards then follow these steps.

1)  Drag and drop a viewController from object library

[image]

2) repeat step 1 and 2 of first method but this time do not create an Xib file

3) select your newly draged droped ViewController and assign it the new class as follows

[image]
Now you have a new ViewController with an associated swift file.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but at your big step 2 `

2) Select UIViewController as your Base Class and name your class and also check the checkbox with "also create Xib File" click next and click finish.` I cannot check the "also create XIB file" since the checkbox is disabled. And when the file is created, it's flagged with an error `No such module "Cocoa" `

Comment: Please make sure you have selected ios->source and cocoa touch class instead of cocoa class

Comment: my pleasure :-)